# Textbook GMM/Convergence Question

Tags: self-study, convergence, generalized-moments

Consider a binary random variable X that satisfies:
 $Pr(X = 0) = \theta \ \ \ $   and 
$Pr(X = 1) = 1−\theta $ 
for $\theta \in (0, 1)$ an unknown parameter. 
Suppose an i.i.d. sample of size $n$ drawn from the
distribution of X, $\{x_{i}, i = 1, \cdot \cdot \cdot , n\}$, is available, and 
$\hat{\theta}_{n} = \frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{i=1}x_{i}$
is considered as an estimator of θ.

Show that for any $\varepsilon >0$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} Pr(|\hat{\theta}_{n} - \theta| > \varepsilon) = 0$$

Comment: This is a self-study question, so you need to explain where you are stuck and why you cannot solve the question on your own.

Comment: Fair point. My hesitation here is that I understand that the Weak Law of Large numbers gives us that $\hat{\theta}$ will converge to $\theta$. $\therefore$ the distance between the estimator and the population parameter will collapse to zero as $n \to \infty$, but unfortunatly I'm stuck on how to apply this formally to show the above. It seems very silly, but I would be comfortable just stating the question above as a statement, as it seems almost trivial?

Comment: Yes this is the weak LLN. So is your question related to a misunderstanding of the weak LLN? Like Borel-Cantelli? Else, there is nothing to show, this is tautological.

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes just stating something helps to kick-start the grey-matter. I can show this with an application of Markov's Inequality. I'll post the answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

We are given that the estimator $\hat{\theta}$ is the arithmetic mean, and if we  assume finite variance of $x_{i}$ ($Var(x_{i})=\sigma^{2}$), then:

$$
\begin{align*}
Var(\hat{\theta}) &= Var[n^{-1}(x_{i}+...+x_{n})] \\
&= \frac{1}{n^{2}}  Var[(x_{i}+...+x_{n})] \\
&= \frac{1}{n^{2}} (n \sigma^{2}) \\
&= \frac{\sigma^{2}}{n}  \\
\end{align*}
$$

Now we can just show this as a straight proof of the WLLN using Chebyshev's inequality.

$$
\begin{align*}
P(|\hat{\theta} - \theta| \geqslant \varepsilon) &= P(|\hat{\theta} - \theta|^{2} \geqslant \varepsilon^{2}) \\
&\leqslant \frac{E[|\hat{\theta} - \theta|^{2}]}{\varepsilon^{2}} \\
&= \frac{Var(\hat{\theta})}{\varepsilon^{2}} \\
&= \frac{\sigma^{2}/n}{\varepsilon^{2}} \\
&=  \frac{\sigma^{2}}{n\varepsilon^{2}} \\
\end{align*}
$$

Now taking limits:

$$
\lim_{n \to\infty} P(|\hat{\theta} - \theta| \geqslant \varepsilon) \leqslant \lim_{n \to\infty}\frac{\sigma^{2}}{n\varepsilon^{2}} = 0\\
\square
$$

NB: I feel like I'm making an implicit assumption of homoscedasticity here too?

Comment: Re: Homoskedasticity: in the question it is written "i.i.d" so the homoskedasticity assumption is not "implicit". Also, for the Bernoulli random variable you are examining, it is already a given that it has a finite variance.